# INotifyPropertyChanged won't update grid in the window

Tags: wpf, inotifypropertychanged, .net-6.0

I've been this for a while now but I can't seem to be figuring out why my code won't update the window. The events are called and the invoke methods are invoked, but still, my window won't update

```
 public class RaceContext : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public Race CurrentRace { get; set; }
    public string TrackName { get => CurrentRace == null ? "" : "Track name : " + CurrentRace.Track.Name; }
    public List<IParticipant> Participants { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<DriverListView> DriverListViews
    {
        get { return _DriverListViews; }
        set { _DriverListViews = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DriverListViews)); }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<DriverListView> _DriverListViews = new ObservableCollection<DriverListView>();

    public void OnNextRace(object sender, NextRaceEventArgs e)
    {
        CurrentRace = e.Race;
        e.Race.DriverChanged += OndriversChanged;
        e.Race.DriverMoved += OnDriverMoved;
        DriverListViews = new ObservableCollection<DriverListView>();
        CurrentRace.Participants.ForEach(item =>
        {
            DriverListViews.Add(new DriverListView()
            {
                Driver = item
            });
        });
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }

    public void OndriversChanged (object sender, DriversChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Participants = CurrentRace.Participants;
        e.DriverTimers.ForEach(timer =>
        {
            var view = DriverListViews.Where(item => item.Driver.Equals(timer.Driver)).First();
            view.RaceStopwatch = timer.TotalRaceTimer.Elapsed;
            view.LapStopwatch = timer.LapTimer.Elapsed;
        });

        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DriverListViews));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This is the list view class

```
 public class DriverListView
{
    public IParticipant Driver { get; set; }
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan RaceStopwatch { get; set; }
    public int LapCount { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan LapStopwatch { get; set; }
    public string LapPercentage { get; set; }
    public int SectionCount { get; set; }
    public string ParticipantName { get => Driver.Name; }
    public TeamColors TeamColor { get => Driver.TeamColor; }
    public int ParticpantPoints { get => Driver.Points; }

}
```

So when OnDriverChanged is called, the INotifyPropertyChanged is called. the window does not update the records
Thanks

Comment: `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(DriverListViews))` has no effect since no new value was assigned to the DriverListViews property. The change notification is ignored. `view.RaceStopwatch = timer.TotalRaceTimer.Elapsed;` etc has no effect because DriverListView does not implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: Calling OnPropertyChanged() in OnNextRace does not make any sense at all.